# How can I update the label of a Polygon Vector after it has been drawn?

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, labeling

I am quite new to OpenLayers. Right now, I have a polygon vector with some styling applied and a label.

```
var style = $.extend(true, {}, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);
style.pointRadius = 15;
style.label = "My Polygon";
style.fillColor = #f00;
style.strokeColor = #000;

var styleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({"default" : style});

var polygonLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Polygon Layer", {styleMap: styleMap});
```

At some point after doing some processing, I want to display the result as a label. How can I update the label? I figure it would be something like this

```
polygonLayer.options.styleMap.styles.label = "Updated label";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right syntax is like :

```
vectorlayer.features[1].style = {label: "Updated label"};
```

Here comes a full piece of code :

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
        // few sample data
        var box_extents = [
            [-10, 50, 5, 60],
            [-75, 41, -71, 44],
            [-122.6, 37.6, -122.3, 37.9],
            [10, 10, 20, 20]
        ];

        var map;

        function init(){           

            map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');

            // base layer
            var ol_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
                "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?", {layers: 'basic'} );
            // default style layer
    var style = new OpenLayers.Style({
        fillColor: "#FCC764",
        strokeColor: "#E5BE12",
        strokeWidth: 1,
        label: "My label"
    });

            var boxes  = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector( "Boxes" ,{
        styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap(style)
    })         

            for (var i = 0; i < box_extents.length; i++) {
                ext = box_extents[i];
                bounds = OpenLayers.Bounds.fromArray(ext);

                box = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(bounds.toGeometry());
                boxes.addFeatures(box);
            }

            map.addLayers([ol_wms, boxes]);
            map.zoomToMaxExtent();

    // you update the desired label
    boxes.features[1].style = {label: "Updated label"};
    // you redraw the right layer
    map.layers[1].redraw();
        }
    </script>
```

[And you will find an example online](http://www.empreinte-urbaine.eu/mapping/ol_update_label.html).